# Monogame builduing content runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, monogame

I'm making an editor similar to Unity. I'm using WinForms and I'm embedding a MonoGame window in a form like shown [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1). Everything's working fine, but now I need to add new content to the project and I need that to be made runtime. I've looked into [this](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) example but, firstly it uses the xna content building and secondly, when I run it and load something I can't seem to find an xnb file. So what should I do to build with Monogame builder runtime and have the xnb files?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with mono jet but when I make a new mono game project and add a System.Windows.Forms reference, I can do something like:

```
if(_currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && _previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
{
    using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dialog.Filter = "PNG (*.png)|*.png";
        if(dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dialog.FileName);
            System.IO.File.Copy(dialog.FileName, System.IO.Path.Combine("Content", fileName));
            _texture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

which instantly renders the new texture at runtime.

Comment: That's because the Windows-version of the Content pipeline supports loading of raw files (png, jpg, .wav, etc.). However you're not building the content, so you're not really solving the problem that OP is having.

Comment: Since he's using WinForms he's depending on windows anywas, isn't he? So if he may not need the .xnb why bother with converting them?

Comment: If your really need the .xnb files take look at this project http://sourceforge.net/projects/xnbbuilder/ or take a look at MSBuild yourself (`IBuildEngine` (`Microsoft.Build.Framework`) and `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0` as well as `BuildContent` (`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline`)). **disclaimer:** still relying on windows and xna

Comment: Perhaps (which is very likely) he's making the editor for his game in Windows Forms, and plan to design the whole game through the editor, and then use the resources. Sure, he could just convert all the resources afterwards, but if he can make the editor do it AS he imports (or perhaps to save performance, when he saves), that's a lot more efficient than doing it manually.

Comment: Well yeah the editor is working on Windows but some time in the future I want to be able to export games for other platforms with the editor so I need the building and as @Bjarke Søgaard said I need to build automatically on importing.